# "box date" stuck on screen - windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Does anyone know what's the reason to have this little "box date"[*click for image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Qha.jpg) on the screen at all times? It just disappears when you click any part of the screen or click & drag anything, I have updated all my drivers and nothing....

Running windows 10 [*specs*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLBrf.jpg) updated today, problem started about 5 hours ago...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a stuck tooltip. It's a minor Windows bug, it happens very rarely since Windows 7 or so. It should go away after rebooting, but just changing screen resolution to a different one and back is usually sufficient.